# Angular 1 Non-Assignable Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two angular functions that return properties based on others. This works fine when I am just concatenating properties, but gives me a 'Non-Assignable Expression' error. When I call a factory though it returns nothing.

Case 1 - works (but throws the Non-Assignable Expression error)

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputClearCasePassword" ng-model="clearCasePassword()" readonly>
```

Angular Controller

```
$scope.clearCasePassword = function(){
  return $scope.model.property1 + $scope.today + $filter('uppercase')($scope.model.property2);
}
```

Case 2 - returns an error

Html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputencryptedPassword" ng-model="encryptedPassword()" readonly>
```

Angular Controller

```
$scope.encryptedPassword = function(){
  return encryptionRepository.HMACSHA1($scope.clearCasePassword, $scope.model.encryptionKey);
}
```

and here's what the factory looks like:

```
app.factory('encryptionRepository', function() {
  return {
    HMACSHA1: function(text, key) {
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(text, key );
        return CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(encrypted);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: try to remove brackets in ng-model attribute like this `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputencryptedPassword" ng-model="encryptedPassword" readonly>`

Comment: Hi. does the same thing. Just noticed the error is actually on the first example. Throws the error but still shows the correct response (concatenated strings) but the second does nothing

Comment: Looking through [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign) made me think the problem is exactly in `ng-model` assignment

Comment: You should not use the [ng-model] expression, see the angular document https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/nonassign

Comment: Yep. I think it's because the value is returned from a function then it can't 2 way bind it. I have solved it by using      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputClearCasePassword" value="{{clearCasePassword()}}" readonly>

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` must be an object attribute, it cannot be an expression. Imagine where it is going to save your value if you edit the input?

What you need is assigning the value to an attribute first, and then use it in `ng-model`

```
$scope.password = value1 + value2 + value3;
<input ng-model="password" />
```

---

Ok I see you are using `readonly` on the input. In this case you can use `ng-value` instead of `ng-model`.